# Make a inventory list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a inventory for my gun but I have a problem with the list in my inventory **ui**. This is the code that I'm using for my list:

```
public void updateInventory()
{
    int index = 0;

    if (Buttonlist != null)
    {
        foreach (GameObject ob in Buttonlist)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(ob, false);
        }
        Buttonlist.Clear();
        ButtonId = 0;
        Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
    foreach (Gun item in gunScript.secInventory)
    {
        GameObject temp = Instantiate(getButton) as GameObject;
        Buttonlist.Add(temp);

        Buttonlist[index].transform.position = getButton.transform.position + Position;
        Buttonlist[index].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = item.Name;
        Buttonlist[index].name = ButtonId.ToString();
        Buttonlist[index].AddComponent<Button_Clicked>();
        Buttonlist[index].transform.parent = Content;
        Buttonlist[index].SetActive(true);

        Position.y -= 49;
        ButtonId++;
        index++;
    }

}
```

Is there a fix or a batter way to add items to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `GameObject temp = Instantiate(getButton) as GameObject;`  instead of `Buttonlist[index]`

use `Extract Method` let `updateInventory` method more clear

```
public void updateInventory()
{
    int index = 0;

    if (Buttonlist != null)
    {
        foreach (GameObject ob in Buttonlist)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(ob, false);
        }
        Buttonlist.Clear();
        ButtonId = 0;
        Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
    foreach (Gun item in gunScript.secInventory)
    {
        GameObject buttonObj = SetButtonItem(ButtonId.ToString(),item.Name,Position);
        Buttonlist.Add(buttonObj);
        Position.y -= 49;
        ButtonId++;
    }
}

private GameObject SetButtonItem(string ButtonId,string itemName,Vector3 pos)
{
    GameObject temp = Instantiate(getButton) as GameObject;

    temp.transform.position = getButton.transform.position + pos;
    temp.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = itemName;
    temp.name = ButtonId;
    temp.AddComponent<Button_Clicked>();
    temp.transform.parent = Content;
    temp.SetActive(true);

    return temp;
}
```

`Position` and `ButtonId` seem like are field in the class so,you might use like this.

```
public void updateInventory()
{
    int index = 0;

    if (Buttonlist != null)
    {
        foreach (GameObject ob in Buttonlist)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(ob, false);
        }
        Buttonlist.Clear();
        ButtonId = 0;
        Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
    foreach (Gun item in gunScript.secInventory)
    {
        GameObject buttonObj = SetButtonItem(item.Name);
        Buttonlist.Add(buttonObj);
        Position.y -= 49;
        ButtonId++;
    }
}

private GameObject SetButtonItem(string itemName)
{
    GameObject temp = Instantiate(getButton) as GameObject;

    temp.transform.position = getButton.transform.position + Position;
    temp.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = itemName;
    temp.name = ButtonId.ToString();
    temp.AddComponent<Button_Clicked>();
    temp.transform.parent = Content;
    temp.SetActive(true);

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is great and it fixed my bug with the list but now i have a problem with my Vertical Scrollbar

Comment: What's the problem on your Vertical Scrollbar ?

Comment: Here is the link for the image: https://netane54544-gmail.tinytake.com/media/75cf04?filename=1525350321304_03-05-2018-03-23-18.png&sub_type=thumbnail_preview&type=attachment&width=1199&height=675

Comment: Sorry could you explain more detail on your problem,because I don't know the problem from this image

Comment: I can't scroll down and I tryed to change the size of Content but i didn't work.

Comment: Can Vertical Scrollbar be moved before use my answer code?

Comment: I don't know I didn't test it well you answered my question I will accept your answer and try to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok,Wish you can find the problem soon :)